# Wget with a URL list file, but downloaded file is HTML type, not original type

Tags: wget

I have a URL list file, like:

```
$ cat filelist2.txt 
https://example.org/download.php?fileid=700&filename=Project1.exe
https://example.org/download.php?fileid=799&filename=img.sarah.exe
```

I use 'wget' to download all URLs from this file, like:

```
$wget -i filelist2.txt --user='234' --password='123(123'
```

download is going fast, but I found the downloaded files is not .exe type, but HTML. Also, the file name is not my expectation.

```
$ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 virus virus    1000 Mar 13 10:30 download.php?fileid=799&filename=img.sarah.exe
-rw-rw-r-- 1 virus virus    1000 Mar 13 10:30 download.php?fileid=800&filename=Project1.exe
$ file *
download.php?fileid=7928799&filename=img.sarah.exe: HTML document text
download.php?fileid=7928800&filename=Project1.exe:  HTML document text
```

I don't know why. Why does not it download the correct file?
Thanks!

Comment: Instead, if I use " wget  https://virusscan.jotti.org/vendoradmin/download.php?fileid=7928799 --user='234' --password='123(123'", I always got anthentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the headers from that place you're trying to download it from. It's not set up to let you download a particular file, but rather the page itself.

You might find some success with this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/301044/how-to-wget-a-file-with-correct-name-when-redirected

Comment: Thanks! May I use a URL file instead of a specific URL?

Comment: You could write a script that runs the wget command with the options on each like of the url file you have.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why when I use wget with URL always got authentication failed. like, wget https://example.org/download.php?fileid=799&filename=img.sarah.exe --user='234' --password='123(123'